# TF-Agents getting malloc error while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-agent

I am running on a problem with malloc error, when trying to use tf-agents library for training a DQN.

**Specs:**
M1 mac os 12
TF 2.6.2, tf-agents 0.10.0
Python 3.8 (same results for 3.9)
Im using custom Environment, wrapped into TF env. Everything else are default components of tf-agents without any customizations.

The error appears 9/10 runs, sometimes the training loop finishes with success. But if it fails, it always fails on calling agent_tf.train(experience) on the last line of code.

Thank you very much for any advice!

**error:**

```
python3(11957,0x307c33000) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fc8a9875110: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x7fc8ce5c5a80
python3(11957,0x307c33000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    11957 abort      python3 main_loop.py
/Users/jankolnik/miniconda3/envs/ml_int/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 3 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
```

**code:**

```
# ENV init
env_tf = environment_tf.Environment(
    n_actions=len(environment.Actions),
    random_start_on_close=params.random_start_on_close.value,
    bars=params.bars_count.value,
    data=train_data,
    reward_on_close_only=params.reward_on_close_only.value
)
env_tf = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(env_tf)

# NET init
net = tf_agents.networks.q_network.QNetwork(input_tensor_spec=env_tf.observation_spec(),
                                            action_spec=env_tf.action_spec(),
                                            fc_layer_params=(50, 2),
                                            activation_fn=tf.keras.activations.relu)
tgt_net = tf_agents.networks.q_network.QNetwork(input_tensor_spec=env_tf.observation_spec(),
                                            action_spec=env_tf.action_spec(),
                                            fc_layer_params=(50, 2),
                                            activation_fn=tf.keras.activations.relu)

# AGENT init
train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)
global_step = tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step()
epsilon = tf.compat.v1.train.polynomial_decay(
    params.epsilon_start.value,
    global_step,
    decay_steps=params.episodes.value * 5,
    end_learning_rate=params.epsilon_stop.value)

agent_tf = DqnAgent(
    action_spec=env_tf.action_spec(),
    gamma=params.gamma.value,
    target_update_period=params.target_net_sync.value,
    q_network=net,
    target_q_network=tgt_net,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=params.learning_rate.value),
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter,
    time_step_spec=env_tf.time_step_spec(),
    epsilon_greedy=epsilon
)
agent_tf.initialize()

# MEMORY init
memory = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    batch_size=1,
    max_length=params.reply_size.value,
    data_spec=agent_tf.collect_data_spec
)

# DRIVER TF
train_metrics = [
            tf_metrics.NumberOfEpisodes(),
            tf_metrics.EnvironmentSteps(),
            tf_metrics.AverageReturnMetric(),
            tf_metrics.AverageEpisodeLengthMetric()
]
driver = dynamic_episode_driver.DynamicEpisodeDriver(num_episodes=1,
                                                     env=env_tf,
                                                     policy=agent_tf.collect_policy,
                                                     observers=[memory.add_batch] + train_metrics)

# MEMORY –> DATASET
sample = memory.as_dataset(sample_batch_size=params.batch_size.value,
                           single_deterministic_pass=False,
                           num_parallel_calls=3,
                           num_steps=2).prefetch(3)
iterator = iter(sample)
agent_tf.train = common.function(agent_tf.train)

# MAIN LOOP
time_step = env_tf.reset()
driver.run(num_episodes=30, time_step=time_step)

for i in tqdm(range(params.episodes.value)):
    time_step, _ = driver.run(time_step=time_step)
    experience, _ = next(iterator)
    loss, _ = agent_tf.train(experience)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known error with macbooks using the metal api (like how windows uses opengl, vulkan or directx), you won't be able to fix it on your end, it's a problem with how they implemented metal on both the intel macs and m1 macs.

https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/19

https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/177

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have an intel version of TF, so I am not using Metal (i guess). Nevertheless, if I wrap the main loop in a tf.function, it works fine, but app 4x slower.

Comment: It uses metal too, as long as you’re on Mac you will use metal

Answer (score 0):

Thx anarchy, the issuees you have linked directed me to use **binary Bazel installer** and than hit `pip install tf-agents==0.10.0`.
Now I can use tf-agents and tf for apple silicon, which is FAST!

Comment: Which package did you actually use Bazel to build?